# Extra line when merging csv files

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a function that will be able to merge two csv files (same numbers of column). Here is my function

```
def Gather(fullpathin,fullpathout):
    fin=open(fullpathin,'rb')
    finr=csv.reader(fin)
    fout=open(fullpathout,'ab')
    foutw=csv.writer(fout)
    for row in finr:
        foutw.writerow(row)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

The problem : when I open the final file there is an empty line between the two blocks of rows I want to merge. How can I append directly to the next line of my second document ?
Thanks in advance !

Edit: In fact there are no empty rows in my files. Just for example :

```
f1=open('Book1.csv','wb')
f1w=csv.writer(f1)
f1w.writerow(['bonjour','hello','guten tag'])

f2=open('Book2.csv','wb')
f2w=csv.writer(f2)
f2w.writerow(['au revoir','good bye','auf widersehen'])

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

And then, when I apply my function:

```
Gather('Book1.csv','Book2.csv') # I add the condition 'if any(row):' as mentionned
```

I have now three rows : ['au revoir','good bye','auf widersehen'] , [] and ['bonjour','hello','guten tag'].

Answer (score 0):

Two tips:

- test, if your `row` has a content and do not write it to the file, if empty. This will prevent empty line.
- There is no need to open the files in binary mode, consider using text one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not close the file in between if not necessary, to speed things up;
   instead of passing in `fullpathout`, pass the `foutw`.
2. You could skip empty rows. As `row` is a list this is easy to check content on the rows using `any`.

Thus we get:

```
def gather(fullpathin, foutw):
    fin = open(fullpathin, 'rb')
    finr = csv.reader(fin)

    for row in finr:
        if any(row): # there must be text in at least 1 of the cells
            foutw.writerow(row)

    fin.close()
```

Comment: @RobinAndrews taken from the question :P